# In Visual Studio 2022 is it possible to exclude an entire folder from the Code Cleanup?

Tags: visual-studio

I want the Code Cleanup to run everywhere excepts the folder highlighted in yellow.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround would be:

1. Exclude the folder from the solution
2. Run code cleanup
3. Include the folder to the solution

The errors caused by excluding the folder do not interfere with the code cleanup. I would only exclude the rule `remove unused using directives` from the profile.

Comment: I like this idea, I'll try it when I got a chance